# default access modifier in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, access-modifiers, modifier

I have an interface in C++ that looks something like this:

```
// A.h
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
    //Some declarations.    
private:    
    //Some declarations.
protected:
    //Some declarations.
};
```

The specific form is not important. Since this is an interface, there will be a class `B` that inherits from `A`. In the header file for class `B` I have:

```
// B.h
#pragma once

class B : A
{
public:
    //Some declarations.    
private:    
    //Some declarations.
protected:
    //Some declarations.
};
```

My concern is that I tend to use `class B : A` instead of `class B : public A`, just my bad memory.

So far I have had no issues with this, since it's a small enough project. But will forgetting the `public` keyword affect my project in any sense?

Or more succinctly, I know how access modifiers work but, what does `class B : A` default to?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: Hi, I already took a look at that, it does not address the default modifier.

Comment: It doesn't? `class D : private A    // 'private' is default for classes`

Comment: Might have overseen it, sorry. Thank you.

Comment: You can find the details here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ONLY difference between `struct` and `class` is that in a `struct`, everything is public until declared otherwise, and in a `class`, everything is private until declared otherwise. That includes inheritance. So `class B : A` will default to private inheritance, and `struct B : A` will default to public inheritance.

Comment: @rustyx Sure, but answering the question as asked without mentioning that `struct` works the opposite way would have been misleading.

Answer (score 2):

> *What does `class B : A` default to?*

```
class B : private A { /*...*/ }
```

> *But will forgetting the public keyword affect my project in any sense?*

Yes. Don't forget it.

Consider the following:

```
// A.h
class A {

public:
   void f(){}  
};

// B.h
class B : A {};

int main() {

   B b;
   b.f(); // f is inaccessible because of private inheritance
}
```